# Turning a correlation matrix from a different package into a corrr cor_df object for downstream filtering and analysis

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, tidymodels

Currently, I'm using the WGCNA package for biweight midcorrelation which yields a symmetrical correlation matrix.
However when trying to use corrr for downstream filtering, it seems incompatible with this object. Has anyone had any luck reformatting their matrix in a way that makes it compatible with corrr?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as_cordf()` function from the {corrr} package to turn the output fo `bicor()` into a outcome that {corrr} can work with

```r
library(WGCNA)
library(corrr)

mtcars_mat <- bicor(mtcars)

as_cordf(mtcars_mat)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 12
#>    term     mpg    cyl   disp     hp    drat     wt    qsec     vs      am
#>    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 mpg   NA     -0.868 -0.821 -0.774  0.657  -0.894  0.460   0.677  0.593 
#>  2 cyl   -0.868 NA      0.915  0.864 -0.713   0.796 -0.592  -0.806 -0.520 
#>  3 disp  -0.821  0.915 NA      0.864 -0.742   0.817 -0.445  -0.699 -0.581 
#>  4 hp    -0.774  0.864  0.864 NA     -0.542   0.649 -0.677  -0.726 -0.305 
#>  5 drat   0.657 -0.713 -0.742 -0.542 NA      -0.697  0.0923  0.440  0.707 
#>  6 wt    -0.894  0.796  0.817  0.649 -0.697  NA     -0.232  -0.561 -0.725 
#>  7 qsec   0.460 -0.592 -0.445 -0.677  0.0923 -0.232 NA       0.796 -0.187 
#>  8 vs     0.677 -0.806 -0.699 -0.726  0.440  -0.561  0.796  NA      0.168 
#>  9 am     0.593 -0.520 -0.581 -0.305  0.707  -0.725 -0.187   0.168 NA     
#> 10 gear   0.413 -0.492 -0.596 -0.311  0.716  -0.488 -0.230   0.189  0.729 
#> 11 carb  -0.513  0.567  0.519  0.730 -0.189   0.398 -0.572  -0.560 -0.0801
#> # … with 2 more variables: gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>